# df = pd.read_csv("C:\Python\nycrime.csv") is not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, file, import

```
RESTART: C:/Users/Anup/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/Learning Pandas.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Anup/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/Learning Pandas.py", line 6, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv("C:\Python\nycrime.csv")
  File "C:\Users\Anup\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 686, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Anup\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 452, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Anup\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 936, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "C:\Users\Anup\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1168, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "C:\Users\Anup\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1998, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 382, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 674, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Python\nycrime.csv'
```

Comment: Try to use `C:/Python/nycrime.csv` instead of `C:\Python\nycrime.csv`

Comment: I tried however it did not help. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Try

`df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Python\nycrime.csv")`

Notice the 'r' before the path. It denotes a "raw string". In your current format, the `\n` is converted into a newline.

Raw strings prevent the `\` from acting as an escape character, and is instead parsed like a normal backslash.

You can also duplicate each backslash if you prefer not to use raw strings.

Comment: Hi Bharel, The raw string didnot work. Thanks for your suggestion. May be need to try something else